# Transform term for induction proof

Tags: proof-writing, education, fractions

Could you help me to mathematically show that these two terms are the same (they are). This is the last (but probably the most important :( ) step of an induction proof.

$$First:  \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2(n+1)+7)}{6}$$
$$Second:  \frac{n(n+1)(2n+7)+6(n+1)(n+3)}{6}$$

Thank you! :)

Comment: Get rid of the brackets in both expresions.

Comment: Because the denominator is the same in both cases, it suffices to show the numerators are the same. Just work it out .. you can do it!

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Compare the common factors of the two terms. You can quickly remove $\frac{n+1}{6}$

Hence you just have to prove that

$$(n+2)(2(n+1)+7)=n(2(n+1)+7)+6(n+3)$$

Try expanding both sides and check that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

A (hopefully) more elegant variant:

Once you've factored out $\dfrac{n+1}6$, there remains

- $n(2n+7)+6(n+3)=n\bigl(2(n+3)+1\bigr)+6(n+3)=\color{red}{2(n+3)^2+n}$.
- $(n+2)\bigl(2(n+1)+7\bigr)=\bigl((n+3)-1\bigr)\bigl(2(n+3)+3\bigr)=2(n+3)^2+(3-2)(n+3)-3=\color{red}{2(n+3)^2+n}.$